# I want to load event calendar from Database, The return value lose effect and date does not show

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

My javascript:

```
////////////////////////////// Events Loading  ///////////////
 $('body').on('click', '#eventbnt', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    //var container = $('#loadmorefollowers');
   // $(container).html('<img src="img/loader.gif">');
    var newhtml = '';
    //alert("yes")
    $.ajax({
      url: urllink,
      type: 'post',
      data: {'action': "events"},
      cache: false,
      success: function(json) {
          alert(json)
        newhtml =json;
        $('#ei-events').append(newhtml);
      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr + "\n" + err);
      }
    }); // end ajax call
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="ei-events">
            <div class="ei-event" data-start="2016-12-28 16:30" data-end="2014-12-28 19:20" data-loc="Madrid">
                <div class="ei-name">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
                <div class="ei-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect ratatattatttt dadaddd haha</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ei-event" data-start="2016-09-29 16:30" data-end="2014-12-24 16:30" data-loc="London">
                <div class="ei-name">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
                <div class="ei-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing haha.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ei-event" data-start="2016-10-1 22:30" data-end="2014-12-29 16:30" data-loc="Berlin">
                <div class="ei-name">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
                <div class="ei-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ei-event" data-start="2016-10-21 22:30" data-end="2014-12-29 16:30" data-loc="Berlin">
                <div class="ei-name">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
                <div class="ei-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
       <a href="#" id="eventbnt"> Load More</a>
```

My PHP:

```
$start = "2016-10-29 17:30";
$end = "2016-10-30 08:30";

if($action == "events"){
echo json_encode('<div class="ei-event" data-start="'.$start.'" data-end="'.$end.'" data-loc="London">
                <div class="ei-name">Club opening</div>
                <div class="ei-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ei-event" data-start="2016-10-22 17:30" data-end="2016-10-24 08:30" data-loc="Paris">
                <div class="ei-name">IT conf</div>
                <div class="ei-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</div>
            </div>');
}
```

The event display well when loaded together in html page; But if I call it from PHP through the JavaScript, It will not display with the calendar effect and Date will not show. The 2 events on the HTML display well, but when I click on "eventbnt" to load  PHP. the effect does not work and date will not show both the one in variable.

Please, what can be the problem; Is it the the javascript does not interpret the variable `$startdate` or PHP?

See the attached, the 1st two events load by default with HTML while the last 2 load when I click on "Load More" with "eventbnt"

Comment: Are you getting any errorr on console?

Comment: Might just be because the code is nonsense. Please read the manual for [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 1):

Amend the PHP to return a sensible json data structure like this

```
if($action == "events"){
    $htm = '<div class="ei-event" data-start="'.$start.'" data-end="'.$end.'" data-loc="London">
                <div class="ei-name">Club opening</div>
                <div class="ei-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ei-event" data-start="2016-10-22 17:30" data-end="2016-10-24 08:30" data-loc="Paris">
                <div class="ei-name">IT conf</div>
                <div class="ei-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</div>
            </div>';
    echo json_encode(array('htm'=>$htm);
}
```

And then amend the javascript

```
$('body').on('click', '#eventbnt', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: urllink,
        type: 'post',
        data: {'action': "events"},
        cache: false,
        dateType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            alert(json.htm)
            $('#ei-events').append(json.htm);
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(xhr + "\n" + err);
        }
    });
});
```